# Problem using free() function

Tags: c, linux, free

I have a C program that uses `char *str[xx]` staff frequently.
Some of the strings are filled  using assignment operator(=) and need not be freed.
But some other(in the same array) are filled using `strdup()` which needs to be freed at the end of the program:

> char *str[10];
>
> str[i]="Hi";
>
> str[k]=strdup("hi");

**both of the string pointers are non null**, and freeing str[i] will naturally generate "seg fault".
My problem is that at the end of my program, I don't have a track of which pointer is pointing to a string generated by `strdup()` . can you help my how I can find the string generated by `strdup` so that i can free them up?
thank you

Comment: There is no need to free the strdup() memory at the end of the program.  The memory will be released automatically when you exit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of handling this is to keep track of what has been dynamically allocated, through `malloc()` or `strdup()`.

You have to refactor your program to reach this goal.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no language feature by which you can (portably) distinguish a pointer which points to a dynamically allocated memory from the one that doesn't. You can just manually keep a list of indices for which it was allocated dynamically. Or alternatively, choose to ALWAYS allocate on the heap, if performance is not a great issue.

Comment: +1 always allocate on the heap is the most practical solution

Comment: Or if your string length is bounded by `N`, preallocate `N * xx + xx` bytes in one go and use `strncpy` for assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a naming convention to help you remember which is which:

```
char *str[10];
char *str_p[10];

str[i]="Hi";

str_p[k]=strdup("hi");
```

(or use a structure with a pointer and a flag which indicates that this particular pointer was dynamically allocated)